# mylatexformat | need to recompile the .fmt file each 'new day'?

Tags: miktex, compiling, format-files, mylatexformat

So, grinding throught the learning curve for the excellent mylatexformat package, in an attempt to streamline (i.e., make faster) my edit/compiation cycle for large documents that pull in lots (25-30) packages (including some very large packages that take some time). mylatexformat definitely speeds up the process (big thumbs up!), but there is an oddity I'm hoping someone can explain.

I have dumped all the premable package calls into a file I'll simply call template.tex. I stick \endofdump at the end of the file, and compile it into a template.fmt file using

```
 etex -initialize -save-size=50000 -stack-size=50000 -jobname=""template"" ""&latex"" mylatexformat.ltx ""template.tex""
```

Compilation works fine, and the generated .fmt file works exactly as expected (correctly, and quickly), when I pull it into my main document, using

```
 %&"template"
```

as the first comment line of the document.

But, what is weird is that if I do this on (say) a Monday, and then work on the same stuff on (say) Tuesday, my TeX install (latest 64-bit MikTeX, under Win 10) throws an error:

```
 Command Line:   latex.exe --enable-write18 --src --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "lecture_notes_book.tex"
 Startup Folder: C:\Users\<me>\Desktop\teaching\lectures
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.2)

 Sorry, but latex.exe did not succeed.

 The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
 C:\Users\egc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\latex.log
 _____________________________________________________________________

  LaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

  Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
 _____________________________________________________________________
```

The latex.exe log shows my something like:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:

Unknown format name/engine: template/pdftex
```

If I manually recompile template.fmt on the day I'm trying to use it (or, perhaps more accurately, before the session where I'm working with the document that uses that .fmt), no errors, no problem.

So, what do I need to do to (i) compile the .fmt file once, and (ii) make it 'permanently available', so I don't need to go through the process of recompiling it more than once? I'm fairly sure there is a way to generate .fmt files and add them permanently (which makes this perhaps a 'MikTeX question), but since the mylatexformat docs focus on MikTeX, I'm hoping someone can give me a MikTeX-specific nudge in the right direction.

Many thanks...

Comment: It will probably be useful to know what exactly are you compiling into that format? AFAIR there are some stuff you cannot add into a format.

Comment: Exactly = complete package list?

Comment: after you make the format you will have a `template.fmt` in the current folder, presumably later when it fails, that `template.fmt` is not there, in which case you or some scheduled job or script or something has deleted it, hard to say  without any local information.

Comment: We don't know what you are doing so without any information we cannot even see if we can recreate it on different installations.

Comment: template.fmt is definitely 'there'. Its in the same directory as the document.tex file I'm compiling. MikTex simply doesn't seem to be able to find it. Which is why I'm wondering if there is MikTeX setting I need to tweak to make user-created .fmt files permanently in the path (or some such).

Comment: the latex commandline on line one of your code block gives no indication of a non standard format I'd expect to see `&template`  or `-fmt template` to tell tex to use the format (although I don't use miktex personally)

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if its because my MikTeX installs are for 'me only' (meaing, its installed in a directory tree of my user account), as opposed to 'for everyone' (which installs in c:\Program FIles\...   I'll play around with things and report back. The .fmt file is definitely there -- MikTeX simply doesn't seem to be able to find it. I found a few other Stack threads that have given me a clue about what to do when this happens.

Comment: Its definitely the timestamp. Rather than trying to describe the process/issue, I made a short video demonstrating it: https://youtu.be/C27YK4XPwX0  Basically, unless the timestamp of the .fmt file is updated to the day you're using the .fmt file, MikTeX can't find the .fmt file. I tested this by manually updating the timestamp of the .fmt file (making no other changes), and MikTeX finds the .fmt file just fine. Again, the video demonstrates this quite clearly.